# How to preview and INTERACT in many browsers

Tags: testing, cross-browser

What are some services or technologies (free or paid) for

1. Getting a static preview (like a screenshot) of my HTML pages (either local or remote) in many common browser/OS combinations like Firefox3/Mac, IE7/Windows, Safari4/Windows, etc?
2. Actually interacting with a site on the internet through a something like VNC to a virtual machine running many browser/OS combinations?

for the purpose of verifying that it works right

Answer (score 2):

Somebody answered one of my questions posting a link to this [website](http://browsershots.org/). Check it out.
I'm not sure if there's a service to preview interactions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some of these may be outdated:

## Web

### Cross-browser Preview

- browsershots.org
- IE NetRenderer
- Spoon Browser Sandbox
- Webdevlab Screenshots (Browsrcamp)
- Browsera
- Browshot (API)

### Cross-browser Testing + Browser Automation/Functional Testing

- Sauce Labs (Selenium)
- Adobe BrowserLab --> Edge Inspect
- Scaleborn (Selenium)
- Testing Bot (Selenium)
- Browserstack Live

## Desktop/Server

### Cross-browser Preview

- superpreview
- IETester
- IE Tab
- Multi-Safari

### Cross-browser Testing + Browser Automation/Functional Testing

- [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website for testing : http://crossbrowsertesting.com/